# How can set a local host ip address to forward to local host virtual host domain name

Tags: php, server, webserver, virtualhost, localhost

I want to forward different domain names to single IP Address (local for testing), but how can i recognize in pc that which domain name should be linked to which folder?

For example in my windows host file I have added the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1       abc.com
127.0.0.1       test.abc.com
127.0.0.1       test1.abc.com
```

Comment: Question doesn't make sense.  Give us an example of what you have tried and what does or doesn't work

Comment: Can you specify which webserver you're using (e.g. Apache or IIS) so that we can give more specific instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When request is sent from browser to website, the "Host" header is sent which will contain the host name (e.g. `Host: test.example.com`).
2. Web server (Apache, IIS, nginx etc) will check that request header and will route to correct virtual site / folder accordingly to the rules that you have defined in your web server configuration (when creating website in web server, you providing to what host names it should respond to).